# Pegar os dias da semana corrente PHP

Tags: php

Como posso fazer para pegar os dias da semana corrente? Por ex.: Essa semana gostaria de mostrar a seguinte frase:

> Eventos do dia 15 a 19 de outubro

Mesmo estando no dia 16/10, continuar mostrando do dia 15 a 19 de outubro. Tentei o código abaixo, mas quando altero a data, ele marca a data que foi alterada.

```
$p = strtotime("0 week");
echo date('d/m/Y', $p)."<br>";
$u = strtotime("4 days");
echo date('d/m/Y', $u)."<br>";
```

Tentei também dessa forma:

```
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime("last Monday"));
echo "<br>";
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime("next Friday"));
```

Entendo que o problema pode estar em `date('d/m/Y',...)`, mas como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$segunda = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('monday this week'));  // 15/10/2018
$sexta = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('friday this week'));  // 19/10/2018
```

Comment: Show de bola Anderson. Muito obrigado!